# import csv from gmail attachment to google sheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

i need to automate the import of a single sender's attached .csv datas from Gmail to GoogleSheet.
so far i've found this on tutorials :

```
   function RECUP_CSV_PIECE_JOINTE(mail) {
  var fil_email=GmailApp.search('from:'+mail +' filename:csv' ,0,1)[0]
  var dernier_email= fil_email.getMessages()[fil_email.getMessages().length-1]
  var piece_jointe=dernier_email.getAttachments()[0]
  var txt=piece_jointe.getDataAsString().replace(/"/g, '')
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(txt,",")
  return csvData
}
  function IMPORT_DATA(csvData){
  var LEADS=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("LEADS")
  if(csvData.length>0){
LEADS.getRange(LEADS.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData)
    Logger.log("Import terminé")
 }
 else{
    Logger.log("Aucune données dans le csv")
 }
}

function MAIN(){ 
  var mail="contact@mysite.fr"
  //L’appel des deux fonctions
  IMPORT_DATA(RECUP_CSV_PIECE_JOINTE(mail))
}
```

it works but only imports the last mail's attachement, and i need to import all attachments received.

My goal is to trigger this script every hour and compile all attachments on one single sheet.

(sorry i edited this twice, found another tut that partially worked but not as well as this one once edited with Mario's good advices)

Comment: You don't have a sheet with the name `COMPILATION LEADS` in your document.

Comment: Hi Mario, thank you it worked ! indeed i was confused and used the wrong title..Now my problem is that i need to get all mail's attachments imported in googlesheet between two triggers, do you know how to do that ?

Comment: and subsidiary question, the columns titles are reproduced every time a new entry is imported, do you know how to get rid of them ?

Answer (score 0):

On the `GmailApp.search('from:'+mail +' filename:csv' ,0,1)` you are telling the search to get a maximum of 1 thread.

As mentioned on the documentation on [GmailApp: Search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max) the parameters are `query`, `start`, `max`:

> Query: the search query, as you would type it into Gmail
>
> Start: the index of the starting thread
>
> Max: the maximum number of threads to return

You are setting the max at 1.

Comment: Hi, yes i'd like to import datas from multiples mail grouped in one thread, so that would be the correct setting, or am i wrong ? Beside, id like to trigger the script everytime a new mail is received, or trigger it every hour and make it import all the new csv's received since the last scan.

Comment: Have you tried then to use the method [getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getmessages) to iterate over all the messages from the thread and then get the attachment?